# D3 Force - creating markers for links with dynamic refX to reflect varying node size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a marker for each link that has refX = link.target.radius and given each a different id.
I've then added marker-end to each link with the respective id so it picks up the correct marker with the refX specified as per target node radius.

```
    links = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 10)
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#marker" + force.nodes()[d.target].id + ")"})

    defs = d3.select("#svg").append("defs").selectAll(".marker")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter()
        .append("marker")
        .attr("class", "marker")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return "marker" + force.nodes()[d.target].id })
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", function(d) { return force.nodes()[d.target].radius})
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 13)
        .attr("markerHeight", 13)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5 L10,0 L0,5")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .style("opacity", "1");
```

jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/6hustc0h/2/

It looks like everythings working as it should from the console - the markers are creating fine, with different id's. Those id's are attaching correctly to the links and the marker arrows themselves are definitely displaced from the end of the link back up away from the target nodes.

However they're not displacing correctly. The marker with refX = 40 has moved to the edge of the node correctly. The marker with refX = 20 hasn't moved all the way to the end of the node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Setting [`markerWidth`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerWidthAttribute) to *13* will define the width of the viewport into which the marker element is fit into. This by itself is fine and will give the marker a width of *13* in the coordinate system used by your SVG. But, by specifying a `viewBox` on the marker, you have set up an internal coordinate system for the `<marker>` elements' contents. And this internal coordinate system will be used when it comes to evaluating [`refX`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute):

   > The coordinate is defined in the coordinate system after application of the [‘viewBox’](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) and [‘preserveAspectRatio’](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attributes.

   If you set `refX` to the required offset this doesn't take into account the scaling required to fit the viewPort into the marker's width. There is a scaling factor of *13 / 10* to account for.
2. When setting the offset you are missing to add the width of the marker itself, i.e. you are off by *10*.

Depending on your needs there are several ways around that, as long as you are keeping the coordinate systems in sync. In the following snippet I set the `markerWidth` to *10* which will deal with it by having both the external as well as the internal width to be of equal size. This frees you from doing any scaling but will also slightly reduce the markers size in the SVG. If you need the size to be exactly *13* you are going to have to do some calculations, though. The relevant lines of your example might be changed to:

```
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", function(d) { 
   return force.nodes()[d.target].radius + 10;   // Add the marker's width               
})
.attr("refY", 0)
.attr("markerWidth", 10)                         // markerWidth equals viewBox width
.attr("markerHeight", 10)
```

```js
var nodes = [{id:1, "radius": 20, "colour": "black"}, {id:2, "radius":40, "colour":"red"}, {id:3, "radius":30, "colour": "green"}];

var links = [{source: 0, target: 1}, {source: 1, target: 2}, {source: 2, target: 0}];
    

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500).style("border", "1px solid black").attr("id", "svg");
    
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([500,500])
  .links(links)
  .nodes(nodes)
  .linkDistance(150)
  .on("tick", tick);
        
var nodes, links, defs;
        
    function render() {
        nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".node")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius})
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "black");
            
        links = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".link")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke", "grey")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#marker" + force.nodes()[d.target].id + ")"})
            
        defs = d3.select("#svg").append("defs").selectAll(".marker")
   .data(force.links())
   .enter()
            .append("marker")
   .attr("class", "marker")
   .attr("id", function(d) { return "marker" + force.nodes()[d.target].id })
   .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", function(d) { 
              return force.nodes()[d.target].radius + 10;   // Add the marker's width of 10
            })
            .attr("refY", 0)
   .attr("markerWidth", 10)                        // markerWidth equals viewBox width
   .attr("markerHeight", 10)
   .attr("orient", "auto")
   .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5 L10,0 L0,5")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .style("opacity", "1");
    };
    
    function tick() {
    
        nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
            .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y});
            
        links.attr("d", function(d) {
            var x0 = d.source.x,
                y0 = d.source.y,
                x1 = d.target.x,
                y1 = d.target.y;
            return "M" + [x0,y0] + " L" + [x1,y1] + "";
            });

    };
    
    render()
    
    force.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Stripped out the viewBox line entirely and reconfigured the marker path to avoid having to do any additional scaling under refX and after a bit of tweaking they're now applying as intended. Thanks for your help.